# Get user name and password fora particular website from browser history

Tags: c#, google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser

For My application, I want to check if for a particular website, user has user name and password saved in browser history. And if it saved, then read those credential details and used in my application to connect to that website using C# code.
I am not sure if it is possible.

Thanks

Comment: to be a hacker?

Comment: No, no. I will try get user name and password for our website only. So, from our application we will check if user has already provided password and user name in browser sometime, then read it from there. Or else prompt user for those credentials. And then use them to connect to website. There is nothing illegal here :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it's possible as none of the current browsers provide APIs to access secured data. For obvious reason to avoid any third party application accessing this information without authorization and use for malicious purposes.

You can access chrome related password information within browser only. You can access passwords in chrome by browsing to [Link](http://chrome://settings/passwords). This [article](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/manage-view-saved-passwords-chrome) shows how to access the information from within chrome.

In short your task is not possible.

Comment: Even I thought that it might be protected by browsers for the same reason you mentioned. But I found this blog where writer explains how to get credential details from 3 different browsers. https://web.archive.org/web/20150102064610/http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/857320/Decrypt-Stored-Passwords-from-Firefox-Chrome-and-I

Answer (score 0):

To implement "keep me logged in functionality you need to write a UID (not their password or username) to the site cookie (with an expiry date say in 60 days) once they have confirmed their membership username/email address. Then on subsequent visits in the session_start procedure on your server (global.aspx file on IIS/asp.net) you use the UID value in the cookie to lookup in your Membership database for a valid and current membership record.... If the cookie crumb has expired, or no current membership record is found you redirect them to your login/join page to re-enter their credentials or to join your site.
Here is a VB.net session start from one of mine.

```
Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Session("user_uid") = "8a4e9b96-1e80-40f2-af4f-1b4b736bd17a" ' Visitor
    'Code that runs when a New session Is started
    If Request.Browser.Cookies() Then
        If Not (Request.Cookies("UID").Value) Then
            Response.Cookies("UID").Value = Session("user_uid")
        Else
            Session("user_uid") = Request.Cookies("UID")
        End If
        Response.Cookies("UID").Expires = Now().AddDays(60)
        Response.Cookies("LASTVISIT").Value = Now().ToString()
        Dim count As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies("VISITCOUNT").Value & "")
        Response.Cookies("VISITCOUNT").Value = (count + 1).ToString()

    End If
End Sub
```

See your Visual Studio Template projects or search in the Visual Studio Gallery for a template project that implements a SQL membership database with persistent credentials (MS Hello is an alternative also)